# How to join two items in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have this:

```
list = ['h', 'e', "'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

And I want to have this:

```
list = ['h', "e'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

I want to join only two list elements. How can I do that?

Comment: `list[1] = list[1] + list[2]; del list[2]`

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Do you need to join all non alphabetical characters or just those 2?

Comment: it looks like what you want to do is remove a list element. What elements did you mean you want to "join?"

Comment: Joining the two strings, as well as removing a list element, are both basic language operations that are well documented.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: This has an interesting solution [in Haskell](https://repl.it/repls/StupendousSandyAfricanfisheagle) that generalizes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own function and use `.pop` to remove the second element:

```
def merge(myList, a, b):
    myList[a] = myList[a] + myList.pop(b)
    return myList

>>> merge(['h', 'e', "'", 'l', 'l', 'o'], 1, 2)
['h', "e'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use unpacking in Python3:

```
l = ['h', 'e', "'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
a, *b, c, d, e = l
new_l = [a, ''.join(b), c, d, e]
```

Output:

```
['h', "e'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Since Python2 does not support list unpacking (`*`), you can use list slicing:

```
l = ['h', 'e', "'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
new_l = l[:1]+[''.join(l[1:3])]+l[3:]
```

Output:

```
['h', "e'", 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

As John Gordon stated in comments, the simplest way to do it would probably be like so:

```
l = list("he'llo")
l[1] += l[2]
del l[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>>> li=list("He'llo")
>>> li[2:4]=[''.join(li[2:4])]
>>> li
['H', 'e', "'l", 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result what you want :

**Never use list as variable name :**

```
list_1 = ['h', 'e', "'", 'l', 'l', 'o']

print(list(filter(lambda x:x!="'",list_1)))
```

output:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

if you want to join then :

```
print("".join(list(filter(lambda x:x!="'",list_1))))
```

output:

```
hello
```